# Uso de parent::__construct() en PHP para pasar argumentos adicionales a una clase hija

Tags: php, poo, php7

Cuando estamos trabajando en el paradigma de la POO, declaramos la estructura regular de una clase del modo siguiente

```
<?php

class Father
{

}
```

Si ahora requerimos declararle propiedades, lo hacemos del modo siguiente

```
<?php

class Father
{
  public $name;
}
```

Si por ejemplo ahora necesitamos declarar un método que inicialice los valores(propiedades) que le pertenecen a la clase, lo hacemos de este modo

```
<?php

class Father
{
  public $name;

  public function __construct($name)
  {
     $this->name = $name;
  }
}
```

Como nos damos cuenta por medio del método mágico `__construct()` recibimos la propiedad como parámetro y la asociamos a `name`

**¿Qué pasa al momento de hacer herencia?**

Si ahora por ejemplo queremos hacer otra clase que herede de `Father`

```
class Son extends Father
{

}
```

La clase `Son` solamente va a imprimir un valor que es `name` asociado a la propiedad llamada así en la clase principal....

Pero ¿qué pasa si yo necesito declararle mas propiedades?

Es decir propiedades que son solo dentro del contexto de la clase `Son` pero que no existen dentro de `Father`

Si en este momento hago una instanción de este modo:

```
<?php

$obj = new Son("beta", "mail@mail.com");
```

Siendo `mail@mail.com` el valor de una propiedad que solo existe en `Son` pero no en `Father` sencillamente no la imprimirá por que en la clase principal no existe...

¿Cómo lo logro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para poder declarar nuevas propiedades en una clase que esta heredando de otra y seguir mostrando las que ya existen en el método `__construct()` de la clase principal, nos auxiliaremos de

`parent::construct()`

Lo anterior nos sirve para invocar a un método constructor que existe en una clase padre de la cual estamos *heredando*, quedando del modo siguiente

```
class Son extends Father
{

    function __construct($name, $email)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}
```

**ACLARACIONES**

1. Declaramos un método constructor local que solo existe dentro de la clase `Son`
2. A dicho método constructor local le pasamos 2 propiedades, la que es requerida por el método de la clase padre, en este caso `$name` y luego las propiedades locales, en este caso `$email`
3. Al método `__construct()` de la clase padre ahora solo le pasamos como argumento la propiedad `$name` que es la que si existe dentro de su contexto
4. Inicializamos la propiedad local de este modo `$this->email = $email`

**DE MODO TAL QUE ....**

Si hacemos 2 instancias una por cada clase, de este modo

```
$obj = new Father("alfa");
var_dump($obj);
```

y luego

```
$obj1 = new Son("beta", "mail@mail.com");
var_dump($obj1);
```

Nuestro resultado final será

Para la clase Padre

```
object(Father)#1 (1) { ["name"]=> string(4) "alfa" }
```

Para la clase hija

```
object(Son)#2 (2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "beta" ["email"]=> string(13) "mail@mail.com" }
```

Como puedes ver, la primer instancia arroja el valor de name que es el único requerido en esa clase, posterior en la clase hija llamada `Son` me devuelve ambos valores